# Mysql2 ruby gem prepared statement returns nil

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I am using `Mysql2` `gem` to do some basic db update via a `ruby` script. Whenever I do an update via `prepared statement`, I am getting the result value as `nil`,
even when database row is getting updated.

```
Env:
ruby 2.2.3
mysql2 0.4.3
```

Query in question:

```
CLIENT = Mysql2::Client.new(host: '<host>', username: '<uname>', password: '<pwd>', database: '<db>', read_timeout: 10)

update_str = %Q(UPDATE marcom
SET `value` = "<subject>"
WHERE campaign_id = ?
AND flow_key = "<xyz>")

stmt = CLIENT.prepare(update_str)

result = stmt.execute(campaign_id) #campaign_id coming from somewhere else
# result is nil
```

So my questions are,

1. Shouldn't I get a `Mysql2 Result` object back once the update is successful.
2. How can I know if some update is successful when the result is nil even if the update is successful.

Comment: If you want to do low-level database work I've found that using something minimal like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) helps considerably. Using the driver directly is often really unpleasant as it's not designed to be easy to use, just to get the job done. A layer like Sequel gives you a lot more functionality without really cramping your style.

Comment: @tadman I looked into Sequel and it pretty exciting. I was just stumped by this behavior of Mysql2 gem's prepared statement.

Comment: Sequel is nice in that you can start small and dig into it more as you need to. ActiveRecord is pretty heavy-handed by comparison, but also good for some things.